# How big is the set of Hölder continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, holder-spaces

Let $C^\delta$ be all $\delta$-Hölder continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Is $\cup_{\delta\in (0,1)} C^\delta$ a dense subset of $C^0$, the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ in the uniform metric?

In other words, if $f\in C^0$, can we find a sequence of Hölder continuous functions $f_n$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n - f| \to 0, \hbox{ as } n\to \infty?$$

Comment: No need for the union over $\delta$, any single $\delta$ is enough. Just use a mollifier.

Comment: (Or, as mentioned in the answer, Weierstrass's theorem works too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space of polynomials is dense in $C^0$. Since polynomials are Lipschitz on $[0,1]$, they are *a fortiori* $\delta$-Hölder continuous for any $\delta \in (0,1)$. We conclude that $\bigcup_{\delta \in (0,1)}C^\delta$ (or in fact, any individual $C^\delta$) is dense in $C^0$.

Comment: Thanks for this concise proof.